# How to get selected files path using multiselectgridView in Android?

Tags: android, android-gridview, multi-select

I have used a multiselectgridView in my application, Where i am showing multiple images as grid items. how to get the paths of selected images in my gridview. 
I want to add a button in my view . so that after clicking on that button i should get the selected files path as i have shown in the below provided image,means how can i add whatsapp like photo select mechanism to my app. 
[image: Screenshots]

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

GridView mGrid;


private String[] arrPath;
private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
private int ids[];
private int count;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    loadApps();

    setContentView(R.layout.grid_1);
    mGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.myGrid);

    mGrid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapterxtends());

    mGrid.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    mGrid.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener());

}

    private void loadApps() {




    final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor imagecursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null, null, orderBy);
    int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
    this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
    ids = new int[count];
    this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];
    for (int i = 0; i <this.count; i++) {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        ids[i] = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
        int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        arrPath[i] = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
    }


    imagecursor.close();


       }
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   finish();
    super.onBackPressed();

}
public class ImageAdapterxtends extends BaseAdapter{
    CheckableLayout l;
    ImageView i;
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arrPath.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arrPath[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (convertView == null) {
            i = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
            i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            i.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(50, 50));
            l = new CheckableLayout(MainActivity.this);
            l.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(
                    GridView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    GridView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            l.addView(i);
        } else {
            l = (CheckableLayout) convertView;
            i = (ImageView) l.getChildAt(0);
        }

        try {
            setBitmap(i, ids[position]);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
        }
        return l;

    }


    }



    private void setBitmap(final ImageView iv,final int id) {

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {
            Bitmap myBitmap;
            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
                return MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                //iv.setImageBitmap(result);
                setMyBitmap(result);
            }
            public final void setMyBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

                  if (this.myBitmap != null) {
                    this.myBitmap.recycle();
                  }
                  this.myBitmap = bitmap;
                  iv.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
                  iv.getLayoutParams().width = 100;
                  iv.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                }
        }.execute();
    }





public class CheckableLayout extends FrameLayout implements Checkable {
    private boolean mChecked;

    public CheckableLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        mChecked = checked;
        setForeground(checked ? getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tr) : null);
        //setBackground(checked ? getResources().getDrawable(R.color.green) : null);
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mChecked;
    }

    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!mChecked);
    }

}

public class MultiChoiceModeListener implements
        GridView.MultiChoiceModeListener {
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        mode.setTitle("Select Items");
        mode.setSubtitle("One item selected");
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        return true;
    }

    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "text", 1);
    }

    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
            long id, boolean checked) {
        int selectCount = mGrid.getCheckedItemCount();
        switch (selectCount) {
        case 1:
            mode.setSubtitle("One item selected");
            break;
        default:
            mode.setSubtitle("" + selectCount + " items selected");
            break;
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going right way, you need to inflate contextual action mode menu on actionbar, take a look at [Android context menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu)

```
listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

@Override
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
    // Respond to clicks on the actions in the CAB
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_ok:
            //TODO do your stuff here
            mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu for the CAB
    MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
});
```

Add your logic in onActionItemClicked() method.

Add context_menu.xml in menu directory and add menu item

```
<item
  android:id="@+id/menu_ok"
  android:showAsAction="always"
  android:title="@string/action_ok"/>
```

Thats it!

Comment: Sir how can i get the selected images locations ? Suppose i want to store all selected images location in a ArrayList or String [] . how can i get this in my code.

Comment: You have to do this in onItemCheckedStateChanged() method. You will get the selected position and then fetch image path from the array list from which you have displayed the grid items.

Comment: You have stored path in arrPath[] array which can be used to get path in above suggested method!